# Can I filter NUnit tests based on Property in Visual Studio test explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nunit, nunit-3.0, nunittestadapter

Is it possible to construct a Visual Studio Test Explorer search expression that will actually filter NUnit tests based on the **name AND value** of a Property attribute? For example,
something like `Trait:TestSize=Large`.  I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work and after hours of searching it's unclear if I should be looking for documentation from Visual Studio, NUnit, or the NUnit Test Adapter.

```
[TestFixture]
public class SampleTestFixture {
  [Test]
  [Property("TestSize", "Large")]
  public void Test1() { ... }
}
```

More details:

- Currently using VS 2015, but I want this to work in VS 2017 and 2019
- Using NUnit 3.12
- Using NUnit3TestAdapter 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure Im understood corectly, but If you want filtering tests for run what you want based on TestCaseName you should use TestEngineAPI.
For more info - https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Engine-API

```
ITestEngine engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();

TestPackage package = new TestPackage("my.test.assembly.dll");

ITestRunner runner = engine.GetRunner(package);

// Run all the tests in the assembly
XmlNode testResult = runner.Run(this, TestFilter.Empty);
```

where TestFilter.Empty can be something like this:
`new TestFilter($"<filter><or><name>Test1</name></or></filter>");`